# Two websites using one PayPal API

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

sorry I am new to this and I would like to ask if it's possible to have two different websites (domains) using the same PayPal API for taking payments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There shouldn't be any problem - it works at least express checkout, website payments pro and hosted solution

Which API are you going to use?

Comment: I think it's called Website Payments. Thank you, I thought it should work.